# get specific data of multiple same class name jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

hi im just learn jquery a bit
i have an html code

```
<a class="num" href="#" data="number1"> number1 </a>
<a class="num" href="#" data="number2"> number2 </a>
<a class="num" href="#" data="number3"> number3 </a>
<a class="num" href="#" data="number4"> number4 </a>
<a class="num" href="#" data="number5"> number5 </a>
```

how do i get the data from third item if i clicked it?
i already done something like this:

```
$('.num').click(function(){
  var datas = $('.num').attr('data');
  alert(datas)
})
```

and it keep alert "number1" even i clicked the 4th or 5th item? anything wrong with my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `this` to refer current clicked link

```
$('.num').click(function(){
  var datas = $(this).attr('data');
  alert(datas)
})
```

***Working snippet***

```js
$('.num').click(function(){
  var datas = $(this).attr('data');
  alert(datas)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a class="num" href="#" data="number1"> number1 </a><br>
<a class="num" href="#" data="number2"> number2 </a><br>
<a class="num" href="#" data="number3"> number3 </a><br>
<a class="num" href="#" data="number4"> number4 </a><br>
<a class="num" href="#" data="number5"> number5 </a>
```

Comment: thx man, saved may day. already find the solution since morning :D

Comment: @emo  glad to help you :):)

Answer (score 1):

You should refer to `this` to refer to the clicked `<a>` - then, you can access its `data` attribute:

```js
$('.num').click(function() {
  console.log(
    $(this).attr('data')
  );
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="num" href="#" data="number1"> number1 </a>
<a class="num" href="#" data="number2"> number2 </a>
<a class="num" href="#" data="number3"> number3 </a>
<a class="num" href="#" data="number4"> number4 </a>
<a class="num" href="#" data="number5"> number5 </a>
```